# Parameter destructuring (equivalent of python's double-splat)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, double-splat

In python I can pass a dict whose keys match parameters' names with the `**` (double-splat) operator:

```
def foo(a, b):
    print (a - b)

args = {'b': 7, 'a': 10}

foo(**args) # prints 3
```

How to do the same in ES6? This doesn't work:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a - b)
}

args = {b: 7, a: 10}

foo(...args)
```

**NB:** I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't involve changing the signature of `foo` because I want it to be used either way (with and without destructuring). So the following should work:

```
foo(<magic>args);

foo(123, 456);
```

Bonus question: why is the error message "undefined is not a function"? What exactly is undefined here?

(As answered by @Nina Scholz in the comments, this is because `...` requires its argument to have `Symbol.iterator`, which is not defined for objects).

Comment: the bonus question, for objects, there is no symbol iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to do the same in ES6?

There are no named arguments in JS, only positional ones. So the answer is: you can not.

What you can do is either *emulate* named arguments via object passing, as @Andy suggested.

```
function foo({ a, b }) {
    console.log(a - b);
}

let args = { b: 7, a: 10 };

foo(args);
```

Or you could make `args` to be an array, so you can destruct it into positional arguments.

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a - b);
}

let args = [10, 7];

foo(...args);
```

Okay-okay, just for the sake of the argument: it is possible to write a function that will extract parameters of `foo` and yield properties of `args` in required order.

```
function * yolo(args, fn) {
    const names = fn.toString().match(/\(.+\)/)[0]
                    .slice(1, -1).split(',')
                    .map(x => x.trim());

    while (names.length) {
        yield args[names.shift()];
    }
}

function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a - b);
}

const args = { b: 7, a: 10 };

foo(...yolo(args, foo));
```

I would not dare to use it in production though.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was afraid of. ;(

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `args` in curly braces, and again in the argument list for the function.

```
function foo({a, b}) {
    console.log(a - b)
}

let args = {b: 7, a: 10}

foo({...args})
```

Comment: `{...args}` is basically `args`.

Comment: `{ ...variable }` with one variable makes just a shallow copy of the object. it works with babel.